# Not able to access other controllers

Tags: codeigniter, controller

I have worked on a website which was has two domain names.It got linked to one of them on one server.On trying the same on another server for a different domain the website gets linked and opens but it is just able to access the default controller.Anything I try other then the default controller it shows page not found.

Comment: do you have index.php in your url?

Answer (score 0):

there is issue with your .htacces file
just try

```
your.domain.com/index.php/contorller_name/function
```

if it works then replace your .htaccc file at main folder with this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /your_project_path
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```